# Lists get overwritten in loop and switch statement

Tags: c#, list, loops, class, switch-statement

I need help. I don't know how to explain my problem. I've tried posting in once before but it got closed because I can't really explain my problem.
I'm trying to create an application where the user inputs car values such as Car ID, Car Capacity in kilograms and car registration number.
I declare a class like this:

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string capacityKg { get; set; }
    public string reachKm { get; set; }
    public string registrationNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then I declare my List and Class outside a loop in my code like this:

```cs
List<Car> allCars = new List<Car>();
Car vehicle = new Car();
```

Then I use a do while loop inside a switch statement like this to get the value from the user each time:

```cs
do
{
    vehicle = new Car();

    Write("ID: ");
    vehicle.ID = ReadLine();

    Write("Capacity (kg): ");
    vehicle.capacityKg = ReadLine();

    Write("Reach (km): ");
    vehicle.reachKm = ReadLine();

    Write("Registration number: ");
    vehicle.registrationNumber = ReadLine();

    Clear();

    WriteLine($ "ID: {vehicle.ID}");
    WriteLine($ "Capacity (kg): {vehicle.capacityKg}");
    WriteLine($ "Reach (km): {vehicle.reachKm}");
    WriteLine($ "Registration number: {vehicle.registrationNumber}");

    WriteLine(" ");
    WriteLine("Is this correct? (Y)es (N)o");

    ConsoleKeyInfo yesNo = ReadKey(true);

    if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
    {
        allCars.Add(vehicle);

        Clear();

        WriteLine("Delivery unit registered");

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Clear();

        break;
    }
    else if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
    {
        Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        Clear();

        WriteLine("Invalid key pressed.");

        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Clear();
    }
} while (invalidCarCredentials);
```

But when I iterate over the list I want the output to be like this:

- Car ID: ABC123
- Car ID: ABC345

But instead when the user inputs a new value it gets output like this:

- Car ID: ABC345
- Car ID: ABC345

Meaning that the previous value is overwritten by the new value.
I don't want that

Here is the part where I iterate over the list to print out the values on the console:

```cs
Clear();
Write("Search for Car by ID: ");
string searchForCar = ReadLine();

if (vehicle.ID == searchForCar)
{
    foreach (var veh in allCars)
    {
        WriteLine("Value found.");
        // write here all the information you want to display.
        WriteLine($"ID: {vehicle.ID}");
        WriteLine($"Capacity (kg): {vehicle.capacityKg}");
        WriteLine($"Reach (km): {vehicle.reachKm}");
        WriteLine($"Registration number: {vehicle.registrationNumber}");
    }
}
else
{
    WriteLine("Unit not found");
}

ReadKey(true);
Clear();
break;
```

Comment: Please add the part where you iterate over the list and print out the list values.

Comment: Okay sure one second

Comment: I think it needs a `allCars.Add(vehicle)`. Can't see that anywhere.

Comment: @LocEngineer, it's in the first if in the Do while loop.

Comment: I have the allCars.Add(vehicle) inside an If statement, so the user gets prompted if this was the correct info input or not, if he selects "Y" it gets added

Comment: why did you call break  at the end of if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.Y) block? can you post the whole switch case?

Comment: @xdtTransform is right, you need to declare your car variable inside the loop, otherwise the car is already in the list and is changed afterwards. Change the first line in your do loop to: Car vehicle = new Car(); and delete the outside declaration.

Comment: @blacix I called break; at the end to get back to the main menu in the console

Comment: `if (vehicle.ID == searchForCar)` this is your problem I think. It seems you want to search inside the list for a car with matching ID but you check `vehicle` for a matching `ID` (I assume this still holds the info of the last added car) instead of searching in your list of cars

Comment: @d4zed I tried to do that but how do I access the List then in my Case 2 block?

Comment: @Knoop what do you mean? should I search for my list instead?             List<senderDestination> allSenders = new List<senderDestination>();

Comment: @msh The access or handling of your list doesn't change at all, by changing vehicle to a local variable inside your loop

Comment: Inside the whole printing logic you keep using `vehicle` instead of using data from the list. Inside your prints change `vehicle` to `veh` (the actual cars from your list)

Comment: So for example `WriteLine($"ID: {veh.ID}");` instead of `WriteLine($"ID: {vehicle.ID}");`

Comment: "Here is the part where I iterate over the list to print out the values on the console", that's not what the code does, at all

Answer (score 2):

I have tested you code, and it works fine

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Car> AllCars = new List<Car>();
    Car vehicle = new Car();

    do
    {
        vehicle = new Car();
        Console.WriteLine("ID: ");
        vehicle.ID = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("KG: ");
        vehicle.capacityKg = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("km: ");
        vehicle.reachKm = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Number: ");
        vehicle.registrationNumber = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Correct?");
        ConsoleKeyInfo yesNo = Console.ReadKey(true);

        if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.Y)
        {
            AllCars.Add(vehicle);
        }
        else if (yesNo.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
        {
            gotCars = false;
        }

    } while (gotCars);

    foreach (Car item in AllCars)
    {
        Console.Write(item.registrationNumber + "  " + item.ID);
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```

my list output is `Car123-Car456-Car789` (if input was correct)